# CSS3 - How to crossfade images of unknown height AND center them vertically AND horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fade

Yep. The title about sums it up. Need to crossfade images on hover, preferably with CSS only. The width and height are unknown as I'm using Wordpress created thumbnails.

I suppose I could determine the width and height through javascript and apply a margin-left: 50% and half the width negative left value but I'd rather not if possible.

I've tried messing with the display property and the top and left properties but no luck.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="product_image_container">
    <img class="product_image1" src="little_apollo_blueprint.jpg" alt="Featured Image">
    <img class="product_image2" src="little_apollo.jpg" alt="Featured Image">
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.product_image_container {
    position: relative;
}

.product_image1, .product_image2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

.product_image2 {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.product_image2:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can do this with CSS by setting `display` on the parent `div` to `table-cell` then you have access to `vertical-align: middle;` and `text-align: center;`. You'll probably need another container `div` to get them to overlay each other correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is making the images the size of the container and triggering animation on hover. The secondary image is hidden outside of the container and it slides over on hover. I changed the functionality slightly but using images that fill the box was the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    .product_image_container {
        font-size: 0;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        word-spacing: 0;
    }

    .product_image1, .product_image2 {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 260px; /* change according to your needs */
        height: auto;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .product_image2 {
        margin-left: -260px;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    }

    .product_image2:hover {
        opacity: 0;
    }
```